# How to Insert data of flat file into two sql tables using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I m a bit new to SSIS and wanted to know how can we Insert data of flat file in two sql tables.some of the columns of the flat file are Inserted in one tables and based on one Indicator present in the flat file I wanted to Insert the next column in another table on the basis of account number.
Some additional records are being sent now in the flat file along with the old data.
As mentioned based on the Indicator memo(new field sent in the flat file) needs to inserted in the history table.I tried to conditional split the data and then Insert but somehow didn't work then I tried writing a query in ole dB command but that is also not working.

Comment: This would be easier to understand if you showed some sample data. As is, it's difficult to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Please don't add it in a comment. Please edit your original question and add it in there. Put a couple of lines in and explain what you want to do with it. RIght now your quesiton doesn't make any sense at all

Comment: If you want all rows in table1 and some rows in table2 then I would do two data 
 flow tasks.  One would contain conditional split, the other would just map the source to the destination.